# While loop and char

Tags: c++, loops

The code should ask the user a letter and then show the ASCII number equivalent of it up to 3 times. But all it does is just ask the user the character 1 time and show the ASCII of it, while it should ask the question 3 times.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char asciiCharacterNumber = 0;

    while(asciiCharacterNumber <= 3) {
        cout << "Character:: ";
        cin >> asciiCharacterNumber;
        cout << "Value of ASCII: " << (int)asciiCharacterNumber << endl;
        asciiCharacterNumber++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You use `asciiCharacterNumber` to both count the iterations of the loop *and* store the user's input. Thus the loop will continue until the user enters a character whose ASCII value is 2 or greater. Perhaps you should use different variables for different tasks.

Comment: [You are reading from an istream without checking the result](http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#istream-check)

Comment: you don't need to cast to int, `+asciiCharacterNumber` will do the trick

Answer (score 4):

You are reading (using `cin`) into the same `asciiCharacterNumber` variable. Since the printable chars have ASCII values larger than 3, the first character a user would normally input would terminate the loop.

One way to solve this is to separate the variable used for reading and the counter:

```
int counter = 0;
char asciiCharacterNumber;

while (counter < 3) {
    cout << "Character:: ";
    cin >> asciiCharacterNumber;
    cout << "Value of ASCII: " << (int)asciiCharacterNumber << endl;
    counter++;
}
```

EDIT:

If you want a loop that iterates three times, a `for` loop may be more appropriate:

```
char asciiCharacterNumber;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    cout << "Character:: ";
    cin >> asciiCharacterNumber;
    cout << "Value of ASCII: " << (int)asciiCharacterNumber << endl;
}
```